# Refreshing a Pivot table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

I am trying to refresh automatically a pivot table with Powershell script that calls a vba code in an excel.
my powershell code is th following.

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open("$para_temp\RapportPalettes.xlsm")
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item("source")
$excel.Run('Import')
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item("TCD")
$excel.Run('MAJ')
```

the first macro "Import" works just fine. But the second "MAJ" that refreshes the Pivot table with the new data in source doesn't

I tried first this macro in maj :

```
Sub maj()

Dim pt As PivotTable



    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TCD")

    pt.RefreshTable

End Sub
```

I don't get any error but my pivote table isn't refreshed and i have to do it manually.

Then I tried this one to change the pivot table's source of data :

```
Sub MAJ()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim SrcData As String
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache

'Determine the data range you want to pivot
  Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
  SrcData = sht.Name & "!" & Range("A1:Z10000").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create New Pivot Cache from Source Data
  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

'Change which Pivot Cache the Pivot Table is referring to
  Worksheets("TCD").Activate
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TCD").ChangePivotCach (pvtCache)

End Sub
```

but i have an 438 error in the VBA : object doesn't support this property or method for this line

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TCD").ChangePivotCach (pvtCache)
```

could you please Help ?

**EDIT :**

as you can see, I do have a worksheet and a pivot table named TCD. 
[image: Worsheet]

[image: Pivot table]

**EDIT :** 
In fact the macro is working, i tested it by creating a button that calls it.
It doesn't work when i call it with powershell

Comment: shouldn't it be, '.ChangePivotCache' and not, '.ChangePivotCach'?

Comment: Yes it was just a tipping error. I still get the same error :object doesn't support this property or method, and for the same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem which was a bit stupid. In fact I was refreshing the Pivot Table but I wasn't saving the changes.

This is the macro I finally used and I used the same powershell script:

```
Sub Test()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim TCD As PivotTable
     For Each TCD In Worksheets("TCD").PivotTables
          TCD.RefreshTable
     Next
     ThisWorkbook.Save

     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Thanks for all

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below to refresh the `PivotTable` named `"TCD"` in worksheet `"TCD"` with the updated `PivotCache`.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub MAJ()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim SrcData As String
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvtTbl As PivotTable

'Determine the data range you want to pivot
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
SrcData = sht.Range("A1:Z10000").Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)

'Create New Pivot Cache from Source Data
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)

'Set the pivot table object
Set pvtTbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TCD").PivotTables("TCD")
With pvtTbl
    .ChangePivotCache pvtCache 'Change which Pivot Cache the Pivot Table is referring to
    .RefreshTable ' refresh the Pivot Table
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i get error 1004 : can't read the proprety PivotTables of the class Worsheet on this line : Set pvtTbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TCD").PivotTables("TCD")

Comment: @SouhailOuabi  so it's either you don't have a worksheet named "TCD", or you don't have a Pivot Table named "TCD" in that worksheet

Comment: I do have booth as you can see in my edit (Sorry it's in french)

Comment: @SouhailOuabi iv'e edited my code try it, I've tested and it worked for me. Make sure you have valid data from column A to column Z, until row 10000 ! (you can't have blank rows in the middle)

Comment: it doesn't give any error but still, the pivot table is not refreshed !

Comment: When i create a button in the Excel and i run with it the VBA it works !! but when i try it aumatically with powershell it doesn't !! this is driving me crazy

Comment: @SouhailOuabi sorry, I know nothing about _PowerShell_, only **VBA**

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Comment: please how do i change the range from sht.Range("A1:Z10000") to the be automatic and select the actual lines that are there.

Comment: @SouhailOuabi is the number of your columns constant ? what is it ?

Comment: The number of columns is constant but the number of lines is not. I importa data from a CSV to "Source" tab then a refresh the pivot table. so the number fo lines changes.